# Group_by returns just one row while aggregate returns the expected outcome

Tags: group-by, dplyr, posixct

I am currently stuck at the post-processing of some EddyData. Following an example (https://github.com/bgctw/REddyProc/blob/master/vignettes/aggUncertainty.md) I came up with an unexpected outcome of `group_by` which is reproducible but I don't understand why.

Group_by returns just one row while aggregate gives the expected outcome.

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(tidyverse)

#create example data frame
date.time <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:30:00"), to=as.POSIXct("2015-01-03 00:30:00"),by="30 mins")
nee <- runif(length(date.time),-200,200)
df <- data.frame(date.time, nee)

#calculate day of the year
df <- df %>% mutate(
  date.time = df$date.time
  , DoY = as.POSIXlt(date.time - 15*60)$yday # midnight belongs to the previous
)

#trying to summarise nee for each day
aggDay <- df %>% group_by(DoY) %>% summarise(nee=sum(nee))
aggDay
       nee
1 322.1195
```

aggDay just returns one row while `aggregate` would work in this case

```
aggregate(df$nee, by=list(df$DoY), sum)
  Group.1          x
1       0  -25.15698
2       1  448.13960
3       2 -100.86310
```

Unfortunately, the original code involves some further calculations which is the reason why I'd like to stay with `group_by`.

```
#original code, not reproducible here
aggDay <- df %>% group_by(DoY) %>% 
  summarise(
    DateTime = first(DateTime)
    , nRec = sum( NEE_uStar_fqc == 0, na.rm = TRUE)
    , nEff = computeEffectiveNumObs(
      resid, effAcf = !!autoCorr, na.rm = TRUE)
    , NEE = mean(NEE_uStar_f, na.rm = TRUE)
    , sdNEE = if (nEff <= 1) NA_real_ else sqrt(
      mean(NEE_uStar_fsd^2, na.rm = TRUE) / (nEff - 1)) 
    , sdNEEuncorr = if (nRec == 0) NA_real_ else sqrt(
      mean(NEE_uStar_fsd^2, na.rm = TRUE) / (nRec - 1))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I restarted RStudio and now it works. Don't ask me. There must have been a problem with another loaded package.